# Cannot select a pattern as defaultIndex on Kibana

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

So I am trying to get kibana to work with elasticsearch (without logstash .. We index the events directly to elasticsearch) and for some reason everytime I click on the "star" icon to make my pattern a defaultIndex it keeps reverting it back. I don't see any error in the logs either .. Here's the output that I see in the logs when i click on the "star" icon :

```
{"@timestamp":"2015-06-10T15:04:08.628Z","level":"info","message":"POST /.kibana/config/4.0.3/_update 200 - 4ms","node_env":"production","request":{"method":"POST","url":"/elasticsearch/.kibana/config/4.0.3/_update","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0","accept":"application/json, text/plain, /","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/","content-length":"35","cookie":"mp_75ac3e60a415a533d2cfa1c2cce55f42_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22kby9hyc2w0tpa4s31415908364663%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22companyId%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%22companyName%22%3A%20%22Fluig%20Default%20Company%22%2C%22userName%22%3A%20%22admin%40totvs.com%22%2C%22userOrigin%22%3A%20%22CP_ADMIN%22%2C%22userRole%2...; fbm_832538890127683=base_domain=.localhost","connection":"keep-alive","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":61716},"response":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":4,"contentLength":65}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-06-10T15:04:08.643Z","level":"info","message":"POST /_mget?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1433948336937 200 - 2ms","node_env":"production","request":{"method":"POST","url":"/elasticsearch/_mget?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1433948336937","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0","accept":"application/json, text/plain, /","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/","content-length":"62","cookie":"mp_75ac3e60a415a533d2cfa1c2cce55f42_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22kby9hyc2w0tpa4s31415908364663%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22companyId%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%22companyName%22%3A%20%22Fluig%20Default%20Company%22%2C%22userName%22%3A%20%22admin%40totvs.com%22%2C%22userOrigin%22%3A%20%22CP_ADMIN%22%2C%22userRole%2...; fbm_832538890127683=base_domain=.localhost","connection":"keep-alive","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":61716},"response":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":2,"contentLength":102}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-06-10T15:04:08.859Z","level":"info","message":"POST /.kibana/config/4.0.3 200 - 3ms","node_env":"production","request":{"method":"POST","url":"/elasticsearch/.kibana/config/4.0.3","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0","accept":"application/json, text/plain, /","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/","content-length":"2","cookie":"mp_75ac3e60a415a533d2cfa1c2cce55f42_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22kby9hyc2w0tpa4s31415908364663%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22companyId%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%22companyName%22%3A%20%22Fluig%20Default%20Company%22%2C%22userName%22%3A%20%22admin%40totvs.com%22%2C%22userOrigin%22%3A%20%22CP_ADMIN%22%2C%22userRole%22...; fbm_832538890127683=base_domain=.localhost","connection":"keep-alive","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache"},"remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":61716},"response":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":3,"contentLength":81}}
```

The indices are already created and kibana was able to find the field mappings as well ..

Tried both on chrome and firefox. Kibana version:
Version 4.0.3
Build 6103
Commit SHA c3487fb

Here's a github issue I created as well .. : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4167

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out .. My elasticsearch cluster was not storing source only index and thus kibana cannot get the actual config documents and thus the problem!